# Why isn't bitwise trie a popular implementation of associative array

Tags: search, data-structures, binary-search-tree, trie

I have to store billions of entries with Int64 keys in an ordered map.
If I use a usual BST then each search operation costs log(N) pointer dereferencings (20-30 for millions to billions entries),
however [bitwise trie with bitmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_trie_with_bitmap) reduces this just to Ceil(64/6) = 11 pointer dereferencings.

This comes at a cost of an array for all 64 children in each trie node but I think that applying the usual array list growth strategy to this array and reusing previously allocated but discarded arrays with mitigate some problems with space wastage.

I'm aware a variant of this data structure is called HAMT and used as an effective persistent data structure, but this question is about a usual ordered map like `std::map` in C++, besides I need no deletions of entries.

However there are a few implementations of this data structure on github.
Why aren't bitwise tries as popular as binary search trees?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I'm the author of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_trie_with_bitmap

> Why aren't bitwise tries as popular as binary search trees?

Good question and I don't know the answer. To make bitwise tries more popular is exactly the reason to publish the wikipedia article.

> This comes at a cost of an array for all 64 children in each trie node but I think that applying the usual array list growth strategy to this array and reusing previously allocated but discarded arrays with mitigate some problems with space wastage.

Nope: That's exactly where the bitmap comes in: To avoid having an array sized for all 64 possible children.